# Too many database connection objects - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, connection

My application is built on java and uses a sql server database.

There would be roughly around 50 people using the application. But i get up to a 900 connection objects in the database and the db goes down during peak times. How to effectively use the connection objects and keep the number of connections on control.

Comment: by default it would be using pooled connection objects. check yours

Comment: It sounds like you are not closing connections. Carefully review your code, use a connection pool, and make sure to call `Connection.close()` as soon as you are done with a unit of work.

Comment: we have a pool manager to create the connections and hold them. For every unit of work done, we return back to the pool.

Comment: Rolling your own connection pool is a bad idea. It sounds like you have a bug there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Control the DB connections below are the Points to Follow.**

1. Check the code if every connection which is created is being
   destroyed after use. E.g. in Every DB Transaction should be on below
   Pattern, if you are using some ORM make sure you are opening and
   closing connections as per ORM provider recommendation.

   ```
   openDBConnection();
   Try{
   PerformDBTransaction();
   }Finally
   {CloseDBConnection();}
   ```
2. Check if you enabled connection Pooling. If  yes then check the
   minimum Connections Property in the connection string or ORM
   Configuration because whenever a single transaction is done on SQL
   Server, it creates the same number of connection that are mentioned
   in  minimum Connections property so may be in your application 900
   connections are mentioned.
3. If your application is a web app or communicating to web services
   then check if you have enabled Web Gardening(Multiple Processes
   handling web requests on the same Server) or Web Farming(Multiple
   Servers are used by using load balancing to handle the requests). If
   one or both of exists then be informed that below is the Formula for
   Connections creation for SQL Server. Total Number of Pooled
   Connections = Total Number of Processes (Web Gardening Number) *
   Total Number of Web/App Servers (Web Farming Number) * Min
   Connections Parameter Value in Connection String.

**For Effective Use:**

Connection Pooling is already an effective way to use connections but what should be the value of connection pooling it depends on your requirement and DB Server Hardware Capabilities. If you are sure that only 50 users will do transactions one transaction by each in a unit of time then simply you need configure connection pool so that only 50 connections can be created.